# Only three of my five threads are executing, synchronizing using mutexes

Tags: c

I am doing an academic exercise for an OS class where we synchronize five detached threads using ONLY mutex locks and unlocks. We "CANNOT force the threads into any serial execution. Once spawned they must be free from external influences (other than the mutexes). The parent should NOT employ a pthread_join."

I am spawning 5 threads, detaching them and then using each threads to read in data and update a global variable. Currently my code spawns the 5 threads but only three of them output their ID's and none of them get into the while loop. Any help/advice here would be appreciated!

Output:

thread: 6156515168

thread: 6156515192

thread: 6156515176

There is a sleep in main which if uncommented provides the expected output, but this would be forcing a serial execution..

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex_lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER; // declaring mutex
int FileNameHelper=1;
int balance=0;

void* detatchedThread(void *param){
    long tid = (long)param;
    char* base = "data";
    char filename[256];
    char buf[100];
    sprintf(filename, "%s%d.in", base, FileNameHelper); //creates data1.in, data2.in... 
    FileNameHelper ++;
    FILE *inputFile = fopen(filename, "r");
    printf ("thread: %ld\n", tid);

    // critical sec line
    if(fgets(buf, sizeof buf, inputFile) == NULL)
        return NULL; // could not read first line
    sleep(1); // make sure each thread runs long enough to get the random update behavior required.

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_lock); //we are in the critical section, lock mutex
    while(fgets(buf, sizeof buf, inputFile) != NULL) {
        int val;
        if(sscanf(buf, "%d", &val) != 1){
            break;
        }
        printf("%d\n", val);
        balance += val;
        printf ("Account balance after thread %ld is $%d\n", tid, balance);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_lock);

    if(buf[0] != 'W')
        return NULL;// last line data was invalid
    
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(){
    pthread_t th[5];
    //initialize the mutex
    if(pthread_mutex_init(&mutex_lock, NULL) != 0){
        printf("\nmutex init has failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    //call the 5 threads, Detach the threads once they are created.
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        pthread_create(&th[i], NULL, detatchedThread, (void *)&th[i]);
        pthread_detach(th[i]); 
        //sleep(1); uncommenting this line gives me the expected behavior
    }
    
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex_lock);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: All child threads will be terminated when the main thread exits. `pthread_detach` does not help you there as I suspect you think it does. From the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_detach.3.html): "The detached attribute merely determines the behavior of the
       system when the thread terminates; **it does not prevent the thread
       from being terminated if the process terminates using exit(3) (or
       equivalently, if the main thread returns).**"

Comment: I suspect the task requires you to use mutexes in the main thread as well to sync with the child threads.

Comment: If you put the `sleep` after the loop, then the code should work, and you haven't forced serial execution of the child threads. Likewise, using `pthread_join` after the loop has no effect other than to keep the main thread alive until the child threads are finished.

Comment: @user3386109, could you elaborate, after the loop in main? after the while loop in the thread? Thanks!

Comment: Doubt they want/allow you to use sleep anywhere. That is fragile and rarely the right way to do general synchronisation. Use mutex or semaphore. If only allowed to use mutex then just have one mutex per child thread that the main thread blocks on in turn until each child thread unlocks it.